# Multiple dynamic variables within a Ruby where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, join, dynamic, where-clause

I've got a joins/where clause of the following:

```
Trail.joins(:filters).where(filters: { param: "family-friendly", param: "over-18" })
```

The variables `family-friendly` and `over-18` will be dynamically loaded from the array:

```
f = ["family-friendly", "over-18"]
```

How can I adjust the above where clause to dynamically add the elements from the array assuming I don't know how many elements there will be?

I've tried using a `.each do |f|` method on the array and replaced with `param: f` but this seems to overwrite the first findings.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Looks like my code does not in fact work. It only returns the secodn instance of param ('over-18'). I'm looking to find ALL trails which have ALL associated filters stated in the array.

Comment: Do you mean by using `AND` or `OR` operators?

Comment: I want to use AND operators. I think that is what the above code does seeing as it works. Just need to load them from the array somehow

Comment: If you want to use AND, why would you ask two times for the same attribute, with different value? wouldn't it be an OR?

Comment: As far as I'm aware my code essentially uses the AND operator? I'm not sure but it seems to work when I test it in the console. It will only return Trails which have both associated filters. Any idea how I load these dynamically?

Comment: @MikeHolford You should be careful; including the `param` key twice does not use an AND operator. Rather, the last value assigned to the `param` key ("over-18") is used to generate the query. Is your goal to select all `Trails` containing all of the `Filters` specified in an array?

Comment: Asking twice for the same attribute results in `warning: key :<attribute> is duplicated and overwritten on line <line>`. You might want to clarify what you're trying to do as pointed @w_hile.

Comment: Ah thanks guys, Yes @w_hile I'm trying to find all trails that contain ALL the filters in the array. A trail `has_many :filters, :through => :trail_filters`. Thanks for the heads up! Any ideas on how to find them with join/where? 

I want to do get an active record result & not an array result so I can use `where` etc in the view

Comment: @MikeHolford Which database are you using? If it's PostgreSQL I may have a solution.

Comment: Yup using PG @w_hile

Answer (score 1):

To select all `Trails` containing all of the `Filters` specified in an array `f`, you could use a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause in PostgreSQL:

```
f = ["family-friendly", "over-18"]
Trail.joins(:filters).group('trails.id').having(
  'array_agg(CAST(filters.param AS text)) @> ARRAY[?]', f)
```

The downside to this solution is that it works only with PostgreSQL.

Also see:

- [PostgreSQL aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-aggregate.html) - `array_agg`
- [PostgreSQL array operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) - `@>` operator

Comment: Thanks @w_hile checked but I'm using SQLite in dev so it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best solution but it seems to work:

```
filtered_trails = []
trails.each do |t|
  if (filters -  t.filters.collect(&:param)).empty?
    filtered_trails << t.id
  end
end
result = Trail.where(id: filtered_trails)
```

Comment: As written, you have a N+2 query problem. To improve the performance, you could write `trails.includes(:filters).each ...` to eager load the filters for each trail. In that case, you would be executing only three queries instead of N+2 (N = number of trails in DB).